# docker swarm http connectivity

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

new to docker and docker swarm. Trying docker and docker swarm both.

initially i had started a docker daemon and was able to connect it on http port i.e. 2375. I had installed docker colud plugin in jenkins and added http://daemon-IP:2375 and was able to create containers. well it creates a container, does my build inside it and destroys the container.

My Query is, will i be able to connect to docker swarm on http port, the same way i a am connecting to a standalone docker daemon ? is there any documentation on it. or the my understanding about the swarm is wrong.

please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: There is quite a difference here between 'Docker Swarm' and 'Docker Swarm Mode'. Do you know which you are using? What is the output of `docker info` and `docker version`?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can connect to a remote host the same way you are doing via the Unix Socket. People very often forget that docker is a [client-server](https://docs.docker.com/engine/article-img/architecture.svg) architecture and your "docker run..." commands are basically just commands issued by the docker client.

If you set certain environment variables:

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp:ip.address.of.host:port
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_CERTS=/directory/where/certs/are
```

(The last two are optional for TLS connections, which I would highly recommend. You'd have to setup https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/ which is recommended for a production environment)

Once you've set your DOCKER_HOST environment variable, if you issue a docker command and get a response, it will be from the remote host if everything is setup correctly.